# Which hosted chat solutions offer the following?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, chat, hosted-service

I am looking for a chat room solution similar to the one on StackExchange to facilitate more responsive communication between the contributors on [Open-Org.com](http://open-org.com). My criteria are the following:

- No Flash (this rules out more than half)
- Full history (meaning that it is possible to access all previous conversation for future reference.
- Very customizable
- No ugly IRC stuff filling up the chat view (I do not want to see who joined an who left etc.)
- No private conversations possible (this is just not in the spirit of Open-org.com)
- A hosted solution with a reasonable price.

These criteria are so different from [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3603/chat-like-chat-meta-stackoverflow-com-in-my-website), so this is not a duplicate question.

The service which matches this the closest is Chatroll.com. However, at 199$ per month their prices are outrageous.

Comment: This is very funny. A few weeks ago, I wrote a script that does exactly such. No databases (chats are stored in temporary folder) and the only requirement is PHP and it being able to CREATE files on the system (chmod directory to 755, or run in Windows). Please contact me for the source (view my profile, go to my site, contact page). It uses JavaScript to update the chat live.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Zopim](http://www.zopim.com) hosted chat ([sign up here](http://www.zopim.com/signup/trial?eref=tmcreative) if you like).  They offer reasonable pricing and a free forever 1 agent account.  I work for a small company and this is the service we use on our websites for live support.  The chat widget for your site is javascript based and you can use GTalk to communicate with your site visitors.

Comment: That is not a chat room, but just one-on-one chat support software.

Comment: Drat. Thanks for pointing that out @David.  Sorry all.  Google Wave might have been a good option if it lasted. Perhaps [https://grove.io ] is the answer.  It's hosted IRC but without the ugly on-screen, real time, logs.